# ValidateHasRole vs RequireRole attributes

Tags: servicestack

What is the difference between attributes such as `[RequireRole("admin")]` and `[ValidateHasRole("admin")]`?

https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#requiredrole-and-requiredpermission-attributes
https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation#type-validators

It does say in the docs:

*ServiceStack includes built-in Type Validator attributes for all Authorization Filter Attributes but as they’re decoupled from any implementation they can be safely annotated on Request DTOs without requiring any implementation dependencies.*

Which dependencies are those? As I understand, `[RequireRole("admin")]` can be put on the service or directly on the DTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[RequireRole]` is implemented by the [RequiredRoleAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs) Request Filter Attribute in `ServiceStack.dll`.

Your [ServiceModel project](https://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure#servicemodel-project) containing your API DTOs should not have any concrete implementation assemblies like `ServiceStack.dll` so if you want to annotate your Request DTOs with Authentication attributes you should use the [declarative fluent validation](https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation) `[Vaidate*]` instead which exists in the impl-free `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` - i.e. the only ServiceStack .dll your Service Models (DTOs) should reference.

Comment: Just found out this very second actually. Tried to annotate a DTO with [Authenticate] and it suggested [ValidateIsAuthenticated]. VS has some good help built-in. Then I investigated which dll's they were in, and found out just what you're writing. Thanks for letting me know the though behind it (dependencies on only SS.Interfaces). Out of curiousity - has it always been like this?

Comment: @specimen yes maintaining [dep-free DTOs has always been a core concept in ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles#data-transfer-objects---dtos) which is what all our multi-project solution templates are pre-configured with by default.

Comment: Any reason `[ValidateIsAuthenticated]` doesn't reflect on the `/metadata` route? No golden key.

Comment: @specimen just tried it, it shows up. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, latest version from Nuget (not MyGet). However found the following:
- ValidationFeature must be added to Plugins 
- It works when attribute is added to DTO, but not if attribute is added to service (no compilation errors, but doesn't do anything).

So for me the resulting instruction is:
Annotate DTOs with the Validate* and Services (class or single methods) with Require* attributes, and _do remember to add the ValidationPlugin_.

Comment: @specimen Yeah, that's it. The attributes are declarative fluent attributes which still require the `ValidationFeature` plugin to enable Fluent Validation.